# How to shift elements with Drag and Drop by using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with Drag and Drop [tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#disqus_thread) from HTML Rocks. The current tutorial basically does a switch of the dragged element and the element it is dropped on. What was in point A goes to point B and point B goes to point A.

```
|A|B|C|  -->  |B|A|C|
|D|E|F|       |D|E|F|
```

I'm trying to change this logic. If I drag point E, it should be in between the others.

```
|A|B|C|  -->  |A|E|B|
|D|E|F|       |C|D|F|
```

This is the [demo](https://jsbin.com/wixogev/edit?js) I have for this.

Should this be done changing the property dropEffect or it will be necessary to create a new div for adding the item we're moving?

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '0.4';  // this / e.target is the source node.
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

  return false;
}
```

Comment: So instead of switching the boxes, you want everything to shift to make space?

Comment: Basically, trying to said that in english, but couldn't find the best way, changing it

Comment: If you are looking for this functionality, I'd recommend jQuery Draggable https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable. If you are doing this to learn, I don't think you'll achieve the desired result without an overhaul. Your logic does not know where the other elements are in relation to each other. They only know what you are dragging and where you dropped it. You'll need to inform it what the order of the list is, and how to rerender it once you move something.

Comment: Checking that library thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this thanks to @tbirell

I'm using the Jquery UI [library](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) for this and change all the logic of what I did at the beginning

Instead of using DIV, I'm replacing them by UL and LI

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class=" ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class=" ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class=" ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class=" ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class=" ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  <li class=" ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

The library is the one that manages the logic of this.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

A link of the working [demo](https://jsbin.com/yutole/edit?html,css,js,output).